# Как сделать так, чтобы gulp.dest() писал в ту же директорию, где был обработанный файл?

Tags: gulp

Вот пример

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imageminJpegtran = require('imagemin-jpegtran');

gulp.task('optimizeJpg', function () {

return gulp.src('./images/**/**/*.jpg')
    .pipe(imageminJpegtran({ progressive: true })())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Мне нужно, чтобы все найденные изображения в данной директории были оптимизированны и записаны в нее же. Но не совсем понимаю как это можно было бы сделать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gulp.dest` поддерживает использование функции в качестве первого аргумента. Эта функция принимает в качестве аргумента файл как `vinyl-объект`. Возвращаемая ею строка используется как директория для сохранения.

Попробуйте так :

```
gulp.dest(function(file){
    return file.base;
})
```

Comment: Самое лучшее решение. Спасибо @avb! Уже кое что написал сам, многопоточный вариант, который выполняет это задачу оптимизации для 2500 картинок на минуту быстрее и с более хорошим логом, но это требует подключения модуля merge-stream.

Answer (score 2):

Укажите в dest ту же директорию, что и в src

```
return gulp.src('./images/*.jpg')
    .pipe(imageminJpegtran({ progressive: true })())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./images'));
});
```

Comment: думаю я не совсем понятно объяснил. Может быть такое, что в images есть еще подпапки. И в каждой из них есть jpg. Нужно чтобы он в каждую заходил и оптимизировал там всё. И сохранял в этих же папках. Иначе мне придется записывать кучу путей. Я немного подправил пример.

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще одно решение моей задача. Оно длиннее и менее удобное чем у @avb но работает примерно на 20% быстрее и выдает более организованный лог, по каждой директории.

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

var folders =
[
  "./pictures/picmanager/",
  "./pictures/news/",
  "./pictures/payment/",
  "./pictures/manager/",
  "./pictures/news/",
  "./pictures/payment/",
  "./pictures/product/original/",
  "./pictures/product/big/",
  "./pictures/product/middle/",
  "./pictures/product/xsmall/",
  "./pictures/shipping/"
]

gulp.task('optimizeImgs', function() {

  var tasks = folders.map(function(element) {

  return gulp.src(element + '*')
      .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{
        removeViewBox: false
      }],
      use: [pngquant()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(element));
  });
  return merge(tasks);
});
```